# How to solve for $x$ in ${\sqrt{9+2x}} - {\sqrt{2x}} = \frac{5}{\sqrt{9+2x}}$

Tags: fractions

How can I solve for $x$ in the following equation?

${\sqrt{9+2x}} - {\sqrt{2x}} = \frac{5}{\sqrt{9+2x}}$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HINT:

Clearly, $9+2x\ne0$

$\implies9+2x-\sqrt{2x(9+2x)}=5\iff\sqrt{2x(9+2x)}=9+2x-5$

Squaring we get $2x(9+2x)=(4+2x)^2$

Can you proceed from here?

Test for the validity of the root

---

$(\sqrt{9+2x}+\sqrt{2x})(\sqrt{9+2x}-\sqrt{2x})=9$

$$\sqrt{9+2x}-\sqrt{2x}=\dfrac5{\sqrt{9+2x}}$$

$$\iff\sqrt{9+2x}+\sqrt{2x}=\dfrac{9\sqrt{9+2x}}5$$

$$\iff\sqrt{2x}=\dfrac45\sqrt{9+2x}$$

Comment: Could you please explain to me the process of squaring to obtain $2x(9+2x)=(4-2x)^2$ ?

Comment: @celis, We have $\sqrt{2x(9+2x)}=2x-4$ right?

Comment: ahh I see! Much appreciated! Don't you mean $2x+4$?

Comment: @celis, Sorry for the typo

Comment: Expanding, I obtain $18x+4x^2 = 4x^2 + 16x + 16$ $x=8$ Thanks!